# Which verses of the NT explicitly state that Jesus was born with a human mind in a human body?

Tags: biblical-basis, christology, hypostatic-union

We read in Phil 2: 5-7 :

> Let the same mind be in you that was in Christ Jesus,
> who, though he was in the form of God,
> did not regard equality with God
> as something to be exploited,
> but emptied himself,
> taking the form of a slave,
> being born in human likeness.
> And being found in human form,

Here, we do not see St Paul telling that Jesus also had a human mind in human body. In fact, verses of the NT including the 'Word became flesh' statement do not pointedly state that Jesus was born with a human mind which took shape with his human body and died with him on the cross. Of course, the term 'human likeness' refers to both body and mind. My question therefore is: which verses of the NT explicitly state that Jesus was born with a human mind in a human body?

Comment: Even Catholicism does not admit this explicitly as a biblical verse. The Church as well as other denominations base this on interpretation of various biblical texts. Besides, as a general rule, we do not do biblical verse search questions.

Comment: "Did not regard" is a function of mind.  Is the question asking what kind of mind Christ Jesus had or has or both?

Answer (score 5):

It can be shown that Jesus Christ was (and is) in possession of a human soul (1).

The apostle says that 'we have the mind of Christ', 1 Corinthians 2:16, indicating that the mind of Christ (as a matter of Headship) is shared in union.

But there are no verses which 'explicitly state' what you are seeking. These are mysteries and can only be understood in the manner in which they are revealed in scripture.

And this is not revealed in the way in which you are suggesting.

The mind is *not part of the physical body* (although the brain is).

The *mind* is part of the *Person*.

*'Let this mind be in you' speaks of the mind of He 'who was equal God', who 'thought (in the mind) it not robbery' to be equal God* - **before incarnation**. And *then* he 'emptied himself' . . . . .

The dual natures of Jesus Christ (the duality of Deity and humanity) are neither mixed, nor mingled, nor merged with one another (for they cannot be as they are different things altogether) they are *united* only in his *Person*.

This is clearly taught in the writings of such as Athanasius at the time of the Council of Nicea.

---

See '*The Soul of Christ*' (1808) by William Huntington (1745-1813) in response to the errors of Garrett.

Comment: "thought (in the mind) it not robbery"  Indeed, the pre-existence of Christ is required to understand this verse. +1

Comment: Yes, agreed @MikeBorden That is how I understand the matter.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that Jesus was born of a human presumes he was fully human, with a human mind. **A human soul does not exist without a human mind** and human emotions.  The Bible does not explicitly say he had a brain but of course that was assumed as well. It does not explicitly say he had ‘emotions’ yet his emotions were prevalent and expressive in a divine way. How the human brain interacts with the mind of the soul – none can know. There is no need to explicitly declare subsets of greater declarations. To say Jesus had a hand presumes he had fingers.

> 27 “**Now my soul is troubled**, and what shall I say? ‘Father, save me
> from this hour’? No, it was for this very reason I came to this hour.
> 28 Father, glorify your name!”
>
> The New International Version. (2011). (Jn 12:27–28). Grand Rapids,
> MI: Zondervan.

**His human mind is why Jesus did not know everything**. He needed his diapers changed and learned how to read and write, etc. He needed a human mind to learn how to walk and talk. Even as an adult, unless the Holy Spirit made his human mind know the thoughts of his eternal mind, he would have known very little.  Jesus needed spiritual wisdom so desperately that he usually got up earlier than everyone else to pray and seek God out of need. Most of our needs are spiritual and have direct relations with our soul (human emotional and mental).  Especially when he approached the cross Jesus needed the eternal mind to support his human soul, his human heart and mind. A human soul can't have meaning without a human mind presumed. Clearly, there is no doubt that Jesus was human with a human mind. He was human in every way, except without sin as we was also God, born of the Holy Ghost.

A word study on the soul linguistically proves historically that the word 'soul' has always included a 'mind'. Early Greek theory includes the human mind in the soul:

> b. Division of the Soul.
>
> Platonic trichotomy (→ VI, 395, 9 ff.) is the starting-point of all
> later divisions. Aristot. An., III, 10, p. 433b, 1 ff. etc. has in the
> strict sense only a division into δυνάμεις and not μέρη. He expressly
> ascribes all vegetative and animal functions to the soul, and thus
> adds these to its structure along with the forces known from Plato.
> **The rational sphere of the soul is specifically human**, the irrational
> and impulsive sphere man shares with animals, and the vegetative
> sphere he shares with both animals and plants, Gen. An., I, 4, p.
> 741a, 1 etc.26 All understandings agree that the power of thought has
> the highest worth.28
>
> Schweizer, E., Bertram, G., Dihle, A., Tröger, K.-W., Lohse, E., &
> Jacob, E. (1964–). ψυχή, ψυχικός, ἀνάψυξις, ἀναψύχω, δίψυχος,
> ὀλιγόψυχος. G. Kittel, G. W. Bromiley, & G. Friedrich (Eds.),
> Theological dictionary of the New Testament (electronic ed., Vol. 9,
> p. 614). Grand Rapids, MI: Eerdmans.

**Biblical text includes the mind under the concept of the soul**:

> ```
>   10 For wisdom will enter your heart, 
>      and knowledge will be pleasant to your soul.
> ```
>
> The New International Version. (2011). (Pr 2:10). Grand Rapids, MI:
> Zondervan.

What potentially confuses the issue is that we actually don't know what we mean when we say 'mind'. What I understand the mind to mean is that part of our inner person/soul that thinks 'logically'. For example, when I see two trees and think to myself, "those are two trees!". I have summed up those objects and counted them in my mind. (I also presume, the human soul has some interrelationship to the brain / nervous system but this is off topic and unknowable). When speaking of Christ, he was fully-God and fully-man. Therefore, I presume he had a human mind but also the eternal divine mind. He was eternal and knew all things but in his human nature he was finite and learned things gradually. I don't pretend to understand how these two natures related to one another inside the mystery of Christ, just stating my assumptions.

When I said Jesus needed the eternal mind to support his human mind, I am therefore specifically noting that: although in my ignorance, I may have thought his divine nature would directly impress upon the mind of his human nature wisdom and knowledge, it seems not. Jesus actually received divine wisdom through the Spirit (at least as a primary means). It's hard not to notice this when reading the gospels. He really relied on the Spirit is a steady constant way making him an example for all humans who need their minds strengthened.

Comment: I would have preferred some scriptural support rather than Plato/Aristotle. Quoting such a source weakens your argument, to my own mind. I am still not clear as to what you propose when you say _needed the eternal mind (sic) to support his human soul._ (Whereas at other times he did not ? !) In the unique case of Jesus of Nazareth I think you need considerable support to assert (in this especial case) that _a human soul does not exist without a human mind_ I very much doubt you can prove that from scripture.

Comment: @NigelJ - yeah I agree Greek Philosophers mean nothing I referred to the Greek thought just to show the use of the word soul in Greek means similar to English - including mind. About the eternal mind, yeah that would be hard to interpret my intended meaning so I added a couple paragraphs on that point because it is central to the way I am thinking about the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Heb 2:17 states quite explicitly.

> For this reason He had to be made like His brothers in every way, so that He might become a merciful and faithful high priest in service to God, in order to make atonement for the sins of the people.

We can either make stuff up like, dual natures of Jesus Christ, neither mixed, nor mingled, nor merged with one another, etc or we can simply accept that there is no *mystery* about Jesus and read the text God has abundantly supplied.

- made like us *in every way*
- tempted like us Hebrews 4:15,16
- died like us - surrendered his spirit to the Father Luke 23:46
- has the same God as us - numerous texts

If he is like us in every way, then whatever we understand about ourselves as God's created humans, then Jesus, the 2nd Adam, is the same. Jesus is without sin, but this doesn't change *what* he is.

Comment: Way too simple. I prefer logical contradictions and mysteries where none are needed. ;) +1

Comment: "made like us in every way"..."except without sin"...so, **not** like us in **every** way.  I guess Hebrews 2:17 is no proof text for this position.  Perhaps there are other ways that He is not like us?

Comment: The "made like" has nothing to do with 'sin or not'.  You are saying the writer of Hebrews doesn't know what he is talking about?

Comment: Adam and Eve were made without sin, so being without sins does not divide Jesus from all humanity.

Comment: Correct. Adam#1 = Adam#2. Both began w/o sin, both human, both given life by God.

Comment: every way is a silver bullet answer - whatever we claim all humans to have as essential to their nature Jesus must have had it. Otherwise he might have been an angel or some other creature.

Answer (score 2):

Luke 2:51-52 gives the picture of boy Jesus who got 'lost' in the Temple and later joined his parents:

> Then he went down with them and came to Nazareth, and was obedient to them. His mother treasured all these things in her heart. And Jesus increased in wisdom and in years, and in divine and human favor.

Wisdom is an attribute of mind, and  `increase in wisdom', a quality of human mind. Had the boy Jesus had God's mind, he would have stayed where he stood -- the bounty of all wisdom to which nothing could be added!